# Wordpress floating/sticky box

Tags: wordpress

i tried and tried but i cant find some plugin that provides me flaoting/sticky box on page. Like that sticky social icons/bookmarks that stick to left side and float. How can i achive that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without a plugin. Just use position:fixed on the element you want to be sticky.

```
your-element {position:fixed; top:10px; left:100px;}
```